# Get previous business day in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, calendar

I have a DataFrame with two columns, a date and a category. I want to create a new date column according to the rule: if category is `B` then the value should the business day closest to the date (only from the past or the day itself), else it's the value of the date column itself.

I define business day as any day which isn't on a weekend, nor present in the list `holidays` defined in the minimal example below.

Please consider the following DataFrame `df`:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

holidays = [dt.datetime(2018, 10, 11)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"day": ["2018-10-10", "2018-10-11", "2018-10-12",
                       "2018-10-13", "2018-10-14", "2018-10-15"
                      ],
               "category":["A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A"]
              }
)

df["day"] = pd.to_datetime(df.day, format="%Y-%m-%d")
display(df)

         day category
0 2018-10-10        A
1 2018-10-11        B
2 2018-10-12        C
3 2018-10-13        B
4 2018-10-14        C
5 2018-10-15        A
```

How do I get a third column whose values are the ones listed below?

```
2018-10-10
2018-10-10
2018-10-12
2018-10-12
2018-10-14
2018-10-15
```

I have a created a function that finds the last business day when working with lists, if that's any help.

```
# creates a list whose elements are all days in the years 2017, 2018 and 2019
days = [dt.datetime(2017, 1 , 1) + dt.timedelta(k) for k in range(365*3)]


def lastt_bus_day(date):
    return max(
        [d for d in days if d.weekday() not in [5, 6]
                            and d not in holidays
                            and d <= date
        ]
    )

for d in df.day:
    print(last_bus_day(d))
#prints
2018-10-10 00:00:00
2018-10-10 00:00:00
2018-10-12 00:00:00
2018-10-12 00:00:00
2018-10-12 00:00:00
2018-10-15 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It will take me a bit to go through them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas supports providing your own holidays via [Custom Business Days](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days).

The benefit of this solution is it supports adjacent holidays seamlessly; for example, Boxing Day & Christmas in some regions.

```
# define custom business days
weekmask = 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri'
holidays = ['2018-10-11']

bday = pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(holidays=holidays, weekmask=weekmask)

# construct mask to identify when days must be sutracted
m1 = df['category'] == 'B'
m2 = df['day'].dt.weekday.isin([5, 6]) | df['day'].isin(holidays)

# apply conditional logic
df['day'] = np.where(m1 & m2, df['day'] - bday, df['day'])

print(df)

  category        day
0        A 2018-10-10
1        B 2018-10-10
2        C 2018-10-12
3        B 2018-10-12
4        C 2018-10-14
5        A 2018-10-15
```

**Edit:** On the basis of your comment, "I just realised I didn't ask exactly what I wanted. I want to find the previous business day", you can simply use:

```
df['day'] -= bday
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this one because it uses already built tools. This answers my question, however... I just realised I didn't ask exactly what I wanted. I want to find the previous business day. This means that if the day itself is a business day, I will not want that one, but the previous business day instead. Any easy fix?
Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty close already:

```
holidays = [dt.date(2018, 10, 11)]
days = [dt.date(2017, 1 , 1) + dt.timedelta(k) for k in range(365*3)]
def lastt_bus_day(date, format='%Y-%m-%d'):
    if not isinstance(date, dt.date):
        date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, format).date()
    return max(
        [d for d in days if d.weekday() not in [5, 6]
                            and d not in holidays
                            and d <= date
        ]
    )
```

Then just apply this across the dataframe:

```
df['business_day'] = df['day']
df['business_day'].loc[df['category'] == 'B'] = df.loc[df['category'] == 'B', 'day'].apply(lastt_bus_day)
```

Comment: Hi, Chris. But what about the category requirement? That's part of what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that part. I edited to select only category B.

Comment: Thanks. Solution understood.

Answer (score 3):

By using `pandas` `BDay`

```
df.day.update(df.loc[(df.category=='B')&((df.day.dt.weekday.isin([5,6])|(df.day.isin(holidays )))),'day']-pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(1))
df
Out[22]: 
  category        day
0        A 2018-10-10
1        B 2018-10-10
2        C 2018-10-12
3        B 2018-10-12
4        C 2018-10-14
5        A 2018-10-15
```

Comment: This is nice, but what if there are 2 adjacent holidays?

Comment: @jpp you mean two holidays ? I think we can then go self define the holiday :-)

Comment: Haha, well over here there's Boxing day & Christmas adjacent. So if the input happened to be Christmas, then subtracting one day will get to Boxing day :S

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.merge_asof` on the subset where `category == 'B'` with all non-holiday business days and assign the date for all other categories. Set `allow_exact_matches=False` to ensure you don't match with the same day for `B`.

```
import pandas as pd

mask = df.category == 'B'

# DataFrame of all non-holiday days
df_days = pd.DataFrame(days, columns=['day'])
df_days = df_days.loc[(df_days.day.dt.weekday<5) & ~df_days.day.isin(holidays)]

dfb = pd.merge_asof(
        df.loc[mask], 
        df_days.assign(new_day=df_days.day), 
        on='day', 
        direction='backward',
        allow_exact_matches=False)

dfnb = df.assign(new_day = df.day)[~mask]

pd.concat([dfnb, dfb], ignore_index=True).sort_values('day')
```

#### Output:

```
         day category    new_day
0 2018-10-10        A 2018-10-10
4 2018-10-11        B 2018-10-10
1 2018-10-12        C 2018-10-12
5 2018-10-13        B 2018-10-12
2 2018-10-14        C 2018-10-14
3 2018-10-15        A 2018-10-15
```

Comment: Thank you. Solution understood.

Comment: @CerramoslosOjos no problem! I updated it with the keyword `allow_exact_matches=False` to match your expected output based on your comment in jpp's solution

Comment: Thank you very much, this was instructive. I had actually arealdy found a solution before asking the question using SQL with an inequality in the join condition. It's somewhat similar to merge_asof which I didn't know existed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by figuring out the business days and choosing the closest one to it based on your category.

```
df['day2'] = df.day
bd = pd.date_range(min(df.day), max(df.day), freq='b')
bd = bd[~bd.isin(holidays)]
df.loc[df.category=='B', 'day2'] = df.loc[df.category=='B', 'day'].apply(lambda x: bd[bd.searchsorted(x)-1])
```

**Output**

```
    category    day day2
0   A   2018-10-10  2018-10-10
1   B   2018-10-11  2018-10-10
2   C   2018-10-12  2018-10-12
3   B   2018-10-13  2018-10-12
4   C   2018-10-14  2018-10-14
5   A   2018-10-15  2018-10-15
```

Comment: This doesn't work when on category B and the day is a business day itself.